# How to access new props.value before render function in React life cycle

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

All:

If I define a component have a property called "value",

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
     console.log("componentWillReceiveProps",this.props.value);
  },
  shouldComponentUpdate : function(){
    console.log("shouldComponentUpdate", this.props.value);
    return true;
  },
  componentWillUpdate : function(){
    console.log("componentWillUpdate", this.props.value);
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function(){
    console.log("componentDidUpdate", this.props.value);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>The value generated by Parent: {this.props.value}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

If I want to give the newly set props.value to state.value( or maybe prepare a value for transition/interpolation ), but all stages before render only have previous value. **Could anyone show me how to get new value before render?**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Important Note: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

---

`componentWillReceiveProps` is called when a component receives new props.

From here you can update the component's state using `setState` without triggering a render.

1. You can access the new props from the **first argument** passed to
   `componentWillReceiveProps`
2. You can access the old props `this.props`

From your example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps", nextProps.value, this.props.value);
},
```

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/finazu/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 4):

For anybody finding this old question via Google, it's out of date. [You shouldn't be using this function anymore](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) and, moreover, there are other solutions that don't involve updating the state! Take a look at this react.js blog article, [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state).

It's not totally clear what OP wanted to do but there are various appropriate solutions in that article. In my case, I wanted to reset a popup window, when a different element was clicked. You can do this with [the key attribute](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state). It works like magic. :)